# AS3 GestureEvent vs TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN +TouchEvent.TOUCH_END

Tags: actionscript-3, multi-touch

Creating an application that requires BOTH gesture(swipe) support as well as simple touch events. I understand that one limiation of the built-in touch support in actionscript is that you must choose either Gesture OR Touch events as input.

So I was wondering if you can easily simulate gesture events using the TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN +TouchEvent.TOUCH_END events? Are they essentially the same thing as using Gesture events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll be able to simulate the gestures appropriately by using the touch events.  Each time a finger goes down a temporary id is assigned to it so you can easily tell if this is the first or second finger down.  In terms of them being the same, it's not exactly the same since the GestureEvents seem to be all dependent on the mobile OS to report as gestures instead of just as touches so any calculation for deltas (or whatever else) would be handled by the OS already instead of you doing it (with the overhead of the VM). http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1ca064e08d7aa93023c59dfc1257b16a3d6-7ffd.html

Answer (score 0):

Try making gestureevents with touchevents.  There are lots of properties that can easily be converted / combined.